# Adjust my input to the right - python

Tags: python, function, adjustment

I'm trying to adjust my text in python, so that the input gets adjusted to the right. I want the last character in the input to be in the 60th position. I therefore used the following script:

```
def adjust_right(s):
    print(' '*60 - len(s)*' '+s)

adjust_right(input())
```

This works if I change the `-` to a `+`, but that does the reverse.

My question is: **Why does this generate an error, when it works perfectly with a `+`, instead of a `-`?**

Could the answer be, that if `len(s) > 60`, we get a negative amount of spaces? If this is the case, how should I rewrite my code?

Comment: Why don't you just `print(s.rjust(60))`? *"that does the reverse"* and *"this generate[s] an error"* don't seem to match up - which is it? Could you provide a traceback, or some inputs and expected and actual outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
print(' '*(60 - len(s))+s)
```

You're trying to subtract a string of spaces from another string of spaces. The reason that + works is that it concatenates the strings. But Python doesn't have string subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

You're subtracting strings due to order of operations, to avoid this:

```
print(s.rjust(60)) # right justify string with length = 60
```

Comment: Would this always be more prefered than

`print(' '*(60 - len(s))+s)`? Or does this method have any advantages?

Comment: What do you mean "due to order of operations"? In python, you can subtract lists from dictionaries if the have a `__sub__` method.

Comment: @Rasmus for a raw text program, it might be better if you wanted to leave space for customization. (then you should make your own method)

Comment: @CrazyPython, I'm not an idiot. I know what I'm talking about. The string is repeated because of the asterisk before the two repeated strings are subtracted, which is not allowed. Thus he forgot to use parenthesis as seen in another answer.

Answer (score -1):

Python has no string subtraction. (This is because it is considered "unpythonic" - most operations like these are syntax sugar/syrup, can be done easily by the programmer, or has functions to do operations)

You should use `' '*60.strip(len(s)*' ')`.  This will take `len(s)*' '` off of `' '*60`. If it can't it won't do anything.

Comment: or, if you feel like you want it, you could always make a decorator that adds a `__sub__` to it. (Don't forget to use `raise TypeError` when invalid)